# Simulate click with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to add keyboard navigation to a pair of next/previous links using jQuery.

I would have thought it would be as simple as this, but apparently not:

```
 $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 37) {
     $('a.next').click();
   } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
     $('a.prev').click();
   }
 });
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is working, what is not?

Comment: What is `document.documentElement`? Also use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode`.

Comment: The links worked when they are clicked, but not on keyup. The keyup successfully prints a test message into the console.

Comment: @vega The root document element - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_documentelement.asp

Comment: use `event.which` instead if `event.keyCode`

Comment: `event.which` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer are you sure? http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: Yup - http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/ujqID

Comment: Your problem is not related to `which` but it should be used instead of `keyCode` if you want to have cross-browser code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (event) {
  if (event.which === 37) {
    window.location.hash = $('a.next').attr('href'); 
  }
  else if (event.which === 39) {
    window.location.hash = $('a.prev').attr('href');
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/vermilion1/pen/eCtnv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't `.click()` an `<a>` tag. You could add this code onload to work:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    window.location = this.href;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all you should define the click events for next and previous links, then in your code change :

```
$('a.next').click();
$('a.prev').click();
```

by:

```
$('a.next').trigger('click');
$('a.prev').trigger('click');
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'define the click events'? They are already links that go to the next and previous pages, what else do I need to do?

Comment: -1 `$('a.next').trigger('click')` is same as `$('a.next').click()`. Description for `.click` from docs. _Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or **trigger that event on an element**_

Comment: I've tried it here: http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/LHCEe Doesn't seem to do anything.